# git fatal: 'development' doesn't appear to be a git repository

Tags: git

I created a new branch and checked out into it:

```
git checkout -b new
```

Then checked for the remote branches:

```
git branch -r
```

and so in the list:

```
origin/development
```

I'm trying to pull the code from this branch into my new branch but getting the error:

```
fatal: 'development' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I'm using git pull development

Also I checked in .git/config and the remote origin is set:

```
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://gitlab.com/myCompany/front.git
```

Why can't I pull the code from the remote branch?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+does+not+appear+to+be+a+git+repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm using `git pull development`

This is incorrect. `git pull` accepts two options mainly `remote` and `branch`. `git pull development` will tell git to pull from `development` remote and `master` branch (default branch is master)

To tell the git to pull the latest code from `origin/developmment` do `git pull origin development`.

Comment: I feel so stupid thank you very much(: